# Securing C3064 Nexus Control Plane

Tags: cisco-nx-os

i have a N3k_C3064PQ-10GX and i want to secure control plane, i want to permit only trusted ip address and deny all other ips, because i am using dynamic ips it s hard to tune the access lists,

so is there anyway that in C3064 permit only trusted ip address and deny other ips?

i have searched a lot but ithas only police action and has only predefined copp rules,

THanks,

Comment: You can create an ACL for the VTY lines and the mgmt0 interface.

Comment: i have applied access list for vty line but some ports such as bgp/tcp/179 still showed as open, my mgmt interface is safe because it has separate vrf and private IP but i have many interface vlan with public IP and i have applied acl for line vty but some ports such as snmp/bgp/.. still showed as open

Comment: You might want to take a look at the official [Nexus Hardening Guide](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/resources/securing_nx_os.html) .